# How to force figure go to new page instead of new column in a Two-Column Document

Tags: floats, page-breaking, two-column

When I use `\newpage` it only goes to new column instead in IEEEtran document style! What can I do to force it to go to a new page as I had use its designated command as well? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: pls see the code in [link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270902/how-to-scale-eps-graph-without-its-texts-being-resized/270912?noredirect=1#comment650538_270912) for working code for this documentclass.

Comment: Please include your code here so that your question stands on its own. This makes it easier to find for other users. And working code is no good - we need code which produces the problem you want help with!

Comment: @cfr I can't put the whole document here, it is lengthy. You can kindly make slight modification in the LINK above by producing some random text using `lipsum`!      newpage will come after the figure command. Thanks

Comment: The question you've linked to also doesn't contain `\newpage` so clearly isn't going to demonstrate the problem you want help with here.

Comment: Isn't it the simplest way to move place of figure including toward end of document, that it will appear on desired page? Use of `\newpage` will break the text flow.

Answer (score 4):

In `twocolumn` mode, `\newpage` only goes to the next column. `\clearpage`, however, outputs pending floats and goes then to a new page:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1] % page 1, left column
\clearpage
\lipsum[2] % page 2, left column
\newpage
\lipsum[3] % page 2, right column
\clearpage
\lipsum[4] % page 3, left column
\end{document}
```