# Why does scaling not apply to node and how to correctly scale a node in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, best-practices, scaling

The following code and its output shows that although the line drawn is scaled, the rectangle node is not scaled.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\section*{Without Scaling}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0, 0) [rectangle,draw,minimum size=5cm] {A};
\draw (-2.5, 1) -- (2.5, 1) node[midway,below] {B};
\end{tikzpicture}

\section*{With Scaling}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\node at (0, 0) [rectangle,draw,minimum size=5cm] {A};
\draw (-2.5, 1) -- (2.5, 1) node[midway,below] {B};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

What is the right/recommended way to scale a tikzpicture such that:

- All drawings are scaled.
- All nodes are scaled.
- But text is not scaled.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4338/18228

Comment: @HerrK. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4338/18228 is not a duplicate because the chosen answer there (the one using `\resizebox`) scales the text too. As already explained in my question, I do not want the text to be scaled.

Comment: Read one answer below that.

Answer (score 2):

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/247761/19372) explains the differences between the main ways of scaling things, namely `\resizebox`, `\scalebox`, `scale`, and `transform canvas` (or `transform shape`). I think `scale` with a little tweaking is your best option (the others change the size of everything, including text). Here is a solution where you define a new command that will be your scaling factor, and then use it in the appropriate spots (so as to not repeat changes). The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\section*{Without Scaling}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0, 0) [rectangle,draw,minimum size=5cm] {A};
\draw (-2.5, 1) -- (2.5, 1) node[midway,below] {B};
\end{tikzpicture}

\section*{With Scaling}
\newcommand\scaler{.5}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\scaler]
\node at (0, 0) [rectangle,draw,minimum size=\scaler*5cm] {A};
\draw (-2.5, 1) -- (2.5, 1) node[midway,below] {B};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You mean something like this?

```
   \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
    \node at (0, 0) [rectangle,draw,minimum size=5cm] { A};
    \draw (-2.5, 1) -- (2.5, 1) node[midway,below] {\scriptsize B};
    \end{tikzpicture}
```